# How to keep html div element inside screen on scrolling with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say we have a long scrollable page, and a separate side block, which is shorter than page, but longer than screen height.
[image]

I'm trying to make the sidebar always inside the screen by one of it's ends.

When scrolling down, sidebar scrolled until fixes with it's bottom to the bottom of the screen:
[image]

Then if you scroll upwards, it will scroll until fixed with top:

[image]

So sidebar will never leave the screen.
It is simmilar to bootstrap affix, but with scroll ability.
Seems to be a common feature, saw few sites with this behavior, suprised I couldn't find ready implementation.
I just can't make it right, always find new bugs in unusual situations.
Maybe there is ready solution in some library?

Answer (score 0):

Today I realised I don't need "fixed" positon and can update offset on each scroll.
Here is my code if anyone will search for the same question.

html:

```
<div id="screen">
    <div id="page">
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var margin = 0;
var sidebarIsFixed = false;
var lastScroll = 0;
var topOffset = 0;

var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var screen = document.getElementById('screen');
var yPos = undefined;

function OnBodyScroll() {
    if (yPos == undefined) {
        yPos = 0;
        var parent = sidebar.offsetParent;
        while (parent && parent != screen) {
            yPos += parent.offsetTop;
            parent = parent.offsetParent;
        }
        margin = sidebar.offsetTop;
        topOffset = margin;
    }
    var windowHeight = screen.clientHeight;
    var barHeight = sidebar.clientHeight;
    var scroll = screen.scrollTop;

    if (scroll >= lastScroll) {
        if (scroll + windowHeight > yPos + topOffset + barHeight + margin) {
            topOffset = scroll -yPos + windowHeight - barHeight - margin;
            sidebar.style.marginTop = topOffset + "px";
        }
    } else {
        if (scroll < yPos + topOffset - margin) {
            topOffset = scroll - yPos + margin;
            if (topOffset < margin) {
                topOffset = margin;
            }
            sidebar.style.marginTop = topOffset + "px";
        }
    }

    lastScroll = scroll;
}

screen.onscroll = OnBodyScroll;
OnBodyScroll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilyad/da543f40/3/

Comment: `[sidebar css] { position: static }` and it will stay there.

Comment: Either static with top offset or margin-top. Problem is, it will lag on smooth scroll, so i need to turn "position: fixed" on and off...